# How many times tangent to a cubic curve $y = x^3$ from a point on it, meets again at another point.

Tags: graphing-functions, curves

As per my elementary knowledge, the cubic curve can have a suitable start point so that if draw a tangent through it, it should intersect the curve at a point; then from this point of intersection can again draw a tangent that will intersect the curve. This means there are a total (maximum) of $3$ point linked together by tangents provided the first point on the curve is chosen suitably.

I want first of all vetting of the above, and the logic (reason) for the above statement.

I have tried manually and have no algebraic/ analytical reason to prove the above. But, my attempts yield only $3$ such points, 'provided' suitable start point is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=x^3$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2$$

Tangent at point $a$ is $$y-a^3=3a^2(x-a)$$

Let's figure out where else does it intersect.

$$x^3-a^3=3a^2(x-a)$$

$$(x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)=3a^2(x-a)$$

$$(x-a)(x^2+ax-2a^2)=0$$

$$(x-a)(x-a)(x+2a)=0$$

$$(x-a)^2(x+2a)=0$$

Hence the next point would be at $x=-2a$.

Hence if we started at $x=a$, the sequence will be a geometric sequence with common ratio $-2$, hence it can go up to infinitely many times.

Comment: A way to get slope is to take 2 points on cubic : (i) diff. $x=(-2)^{n+1}\cdot a - (-2)^n\cdot a$; (ii) diff. $y=(-2)^3{n+1}\cdot a^3 - (-2)^{3n}\cdot a^3$; & slope: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-9\cdot (-2)^{3n}\cdot a^3}{$-3\cdot (-2)^n\cdot a}\implies 3\cdot 4^n\cdot a^2$. Logic for diff. slope can be: my approach gets for tangent from 2nd point with $a': (-2)a$; if 1st point is:$a$, so $a'^2= 4a^2$. But, in code at http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_3iiEyt0dXlou231_12.py,  alternate slopes only are obtained as compared to http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_3vxurN47x6_1.py.

Comment: Have a small linked post that discusses the reason for positive angles of slopes, & summarizes this post, is at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2809994/424260.

Comment: Regarding my first comment, I want to add that my modified way to get slope yields the points for given values of $n$ starting from $n=0$ as : $0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ....$; i.e. after 1st (start) point every alternate point's slope is shown only. This can be seen in the comparison of two py3 files' run shown in the first  comment. Say, my approach (file name ending with 12) yields for 2nd point with $a=-0.22$ slope for $a=0.44$ (of the other file, using your approach); & this goes on repeating ...

Comment: I hope that my 1st and last comments above are important.

Comment: you know the next point by using equation of tangent (which utilizes slope). Of course, you can verify the slope using the ratio.

Comment: By slope of the sequence (as at : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2810521/424260) = $3\cdot 4^n\cdot a^2$, I hope you mean something different than $3a^2$. Please elaborate, as have shown in my first & 3rd comments above, that the two are different.

Comment: slope of any $x$ is $3x^2$. if $x=a$, the slope is $3a^2$. If $x_n = (-2)^n a$, then the slope is $3x_n^2=3\cdot 4^n a^2$.

Comment: But, that means: take start point tangent's slope; then have slope at 3rd point. Continue this with distance increasing by $2$ each time, i.e for point (n=2), get slope for $n=3$; for point with $n=3$ get slope for $n=5$; and so on. Say, for : (i) Point $n=2$ >> $0.22$ -slope $= 30.14$, which is slope for $a=0.44, n=3$; (ii) Point $n=3$ >> $0.44$ -slope $=83.85$, which is slope for $a=1.76, n=5$; (iii) Point $n=4$ >> $a=0.88$ - slope $=89.61$, which is slope for $a=7.04, n= 7$; (iv) Point $n=5$ >> $a=1.76$ - slope $=89.975$, which is slope for $a=28.16, n=9$. Please help.

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: The two py3 files in the first comment, have difference in slopes for different $n$ values. Please verify my statement by running those 2 files.

Comment: [here](http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_QKlzKmDtjSmgRMn.py). In programming, we reuse variables sometimes.

Comment: Have a request, please see my post at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4497807/424260. The reason asking is, after intense 2+ hours, found that have stated the problem wrong. Now, all have left in disdain. Might be no one comes to rescue. It is a rare situation. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a wonderful phenomenon, encapsulated in **Bézout’s Theorem**, according to which two distinct irreducible curves, of degrees $d$ and $d'$ respectively, have *precisely* $dd'$ points of intersection.

**Except** that the points of intersection have to be counted with multiplicity; you have to look for them in an algebraically closed field (such as $\Bbb C$); and you have to look not in the ordinary “finite” plane, but in the projective plane.

In your case, you’re intersecting a curve of degree three (the cubic) with a curve of degree one (the line), in which case there will be precisely three intersection points, suitably counted. You’re drawing a tangent line to the cubic curve, that’s two points already (unless you draw it at the point $(0,0)$, where the tangent makes a triple contact), and the one remaining one has to have real coordinates: that is, you can see it on your graph.

Oh yeah, you say? What about two circles? Two curves of degree $2$ should have four points of intersection. Where are they? Well, I don’t want to go into the details of projective geometry, but there’s a pair points on the “line at infinity”, actually a pair of conjugate complex points, that every circle contains. And any two circles intersect at these points.