# Tangent to Cubic curve has positive slope.

Tags: curves, slope

*This is in continuation to my earlier post at : [How many times tangent to a cubic curve $y = x^3$ from a point on it, meets again at another point.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2809614/424260)*

A brief summary of the previous post :
If take a suitable start point as tangent manually to the curve; then a question arose : will the tangent from new point will again cut the curve. If yes, then how many times this will occur. The selected answer by @Siong Thye Goh, showed that there will be a geometric ratio between such points, with accompanying python code & graphs stated below by him to substantiate infinite sequence of such points.

Also, there are still lingering doubts: I wanted some proof in order to show an infinite sequence of such points, and there came two options that could be could to prove :
(i) convergence of slopes, i.e. decreasing slopes of successive tangents; else 
(ii) to prove a bound on the slopes, that is never violated.

In order to prove it tried to see the first $50$ tangents' slopes, but the slopes are approaching $90^0$ very fast, and all are positive (i.e., the ones made from above to below, & vice-versa), while the points on the cubic curve alternated in each turn from far-left-bottom to far-right-top. Anyway, the alternation of sides and points going still further was a direct result of the ratio $-2$ chosen for the G.P. of such points (as in answer by @Siong Thye Goh).

Could not ascertain why the angles of slopes are nearly $90^0$, & hence could not use the idea stated at (i) or (ii) to prove infinitude of such points;  but have stated the reason for angles being all positive in this post, as shown below.

*Associated code (by @Siong Thye Goh) is at : <del>http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_3iiEyt0dXlou231_10.py</del>
http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_QKlzKmDtjSmgRMn.py*

*Associated graph (by @Siong Thye Goh) is at : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j0frxb5gwt*

Request vetting of the below statement :

The problem's (i.e., tangent from any point on cubic to another point on cubic has positive slope) reason seems that $tan(270^0+\theta)= \tan(\theta)$, & $\tan(90^0-\theta) = \tan(\theta)$
and any angle (of tangent) made from 3rd quad. to first one is having slope of  $\tan(90^0 -\theta)$, and any angle (of tangent) made from 1st quad. to third one is having slope of $\tan(270^0 +\theta)$.

---

*Update * Need specify the angle from upper half(1st quad.) to lower half (3rd quad.) of cubic curve, as lying in the range of angle of slope $\theta' = 180^0+\theta$ to $270^0 -\theta$. This leads to positive $\tan(\theta')$ values; as $\tan(180^0+\theta)=\tan(\theta)$, so getting answer of such slopes as $\approx 90^0$, as $270^0=180^0+90^0$.

Comment: A brief summary of the previous post would be helpful in addition to the link.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Have edited the post to completely detail the crux of previous post. In fact, most of the previous post was solved in chat, not stated in that post, so it helps to state related discussion in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- \begin{align}\tan(270^\circ+\theta)&=\tan(360-90^\circ+\theta)\\
  &=-\tan(90^\circ-\theta)\\
  &=-\cot(\theta)\end{align}

If $\theta$ is an acute angle, then $270+\theta$ is in the $4$-th quadrant and has negative tangent and cotangent value.

- $\tan(90-\theta)=\cot(\theta)$
- The slope of $x^3$ is $3x^2$, in fact, at any non-zero point, the slope is positive.
- The sequence follows a geometric sequence $(-2)^na$ where $a$ is the initial point.
- The slope of the sequence is $3\cdot 4^n\cdot a^2$, this sequence is positive and increasing if the first point $a\ne 0$ and tends to $\infty$.
- To see that it is increasing, the graph of $4^x$ might help.
- $\lim_{n \to \infty}\arctan(3\cdot 4^n\cdot a^2)=\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}.$

This is a graph of $\arctan{x}$.

[image]

- $\frac{\pi}2 radians = 90^\circ$.
- If you start with $a>0$, then the slope is $3a^2$. Hence whenever you move to the left by $1$ unit, the tangent value dropped by $3a^2$.  Whenever you move to the left by $a$ units, the value dropped by $3a^3$ units. How many times do I have to move by $a$ unit step size such that the tangent meet the curve again?

$$a^3-3ka^3=(a-ka)^3$$

$$1-3k=(1-k)^3$$

$$3k^2-k^3=0$$

$$k^2(3-k)=0$$

It is independent of $a$ as long as they are positive, hence to understand the problem, just focus on small number, say $a=1$.

- The tangent is **never** vertical for any finite steps.

Comment: I am sorry for wrongly stating $270^0 + \theta$ instead of  the range bounded by: $180^0 +\theta$, & $270^0-\theta$.

Comment: Please verify my 'Update' to the OP.

Comment: slope is always define relative to a line that is parallel to the positive $x$-axis.

Comment: I do not understand what is $cck$

Comment: So, the $cck$ (counter-clockwise) angle ($\theta'$) of $269.99^0$ is having $\tan(\theta')=\tan(90^0)$. I am taking the vector pointing from the 1st quad. to the 3rd quad. with tip in first, and end in 3rd quad. But, what is wrong is intuition: how can such a far positive $x$ coordinate point have a $cck$ $270^0$ angle with another point on cubic curve in the 3rd quad. with large negative $x$ value. Say, $x=30$ (in the first quad.) making that angle with $x=-60$ point on cubic curve in the 3rd quad.

Comment: Adding further to my last comment's intuition point for having a $270^0$ cck angle, let a point $(x=30, y = 27000)$ makes tangent to $(x=-60, y =-216000)$; with slope given by: $\arctan(\frac{24300}{9})=\arctan(2700)$. This gives in py3  an angle of $89.978^0$ . So, we are getting so big values, but still not intuitive. Do not know how to make such slopes angles intuitive or seem logical.

Comment: I added something to my post, but it is beyond my ability to help you.

Comment: Q.1. Please vet analysis of addendum: It is easy to understand that $k$ steps are needed to move down, so that the tangent from 1st quad. meets the cubic again (in 3rd quad.). Q.2. Is $k=4^n$, as in previous post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2809631/424260. Q.3. Regarding my doubt that it is not intuitive to imagine $270^0$ angle of tangent from 1st to 3rd quad. for large positive $x=30$ to large $-2\cdot x=-60$ values; request some tool that enables one to visualize such un-intuitive angle. If there is a site, applet, or tool; then please tell; else please tell how you believe it.

Comment: you can let $k$ be positive (move down) or negative (move up). The system of equations was $k(3-k)=0$, it has nothing to do with $k=4^n$. As for the last question, I can't help you.

Comment: Q.1. But, if $k\ne 4^n$; then what is the significance of $k=3$, i.e. there is G.P. between successive $x$-coordinate points of $-2$; so how is $k$ linked to the G.P.  Q.2. If tangent is never vertical in a finite number of steps, then why python returns $90^0 (270^0)$ angle. Is this an error inherent in slope computation for large values of $\delta y$, and $\delta x$.

Comment: 1. $k=3$ impy that the next intersection is at location $-3a$ from $a$, hence resulting in $-2a$, it is just an alternative view. $2$. Do not trust what the computer tells you, computers handle floating points and it can only represent finitely many numbers / up to certain precision. Do the maths, do not rely on softwares, be very careful when numbers are huge or small.

Comment: Please help with my post at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2817896/424260.

Comment: note: traveling started, camping at an airport for now. having very limited internet access.

Comment: Hope you are back. Welcome back. Please respond.

Comment: I request help with diagramming a venn diagram with changing values possible, as say at my today's post (& deleted too) at : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtw4H.png Basically, I want that the 3 venn-diagrams be drawn with set $a_{13}$ taking values as $0,1,2$ in each. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: no idea of graphing tool for venn diagram.

Comment: Please help with my question at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2846231/424260. It concerns proving / dis-proving that inverse w.r.t. exponentiation operation exists over the domain of rationals.

Comment: hmmm.... i don't understand your question.