# How to see intuitively that for large values of $x$, the tangent from 1st quad. to 3rd quad. on cubic curve makes $270^\circ$.

Tags: trigonometry, curves, slope

*This is in continuation to my earlier post at : [Tangent to Cubic curve has positive slope.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2809994/424260)*

It is discussed in earlier post (& before that) that given a cubic curve $y = x^3$, if tangents are drawn from a point on the curve to the cubic curve, then there is an infinite sequence of such tangents' $x$-coordinates with  G.P. for $x$-coordinate ratio being $=-2$, i.e there is an infinite sequence of tangents with their $x$ coordinates having a geometric ratio of $-2$. 
The angle of $90^\circ$ (for tangents made from 3rd quad to first), or $270^\circ$ (for vice-versa) is approached very quickly for a small starting $x$ value, say $x=+0.11$; it takes 3-4 steps in the sequence to get slope of a vertical line (i.e. $90^\circ$, or $270^\circ$).

Also, it is shown in code file of the linked post at : http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_QKlzKmDtjSmgRMn.py, that the angle is $270^\circ$ for large $x$-coordinate ($x=7.04$ in the $n=6$ step) point's tangent's slope.

I am at pain to imagine how angle of tangent from 1st to 3rd quad. for large positive $x$ (say, $x=7.04$) to large $-x$ value (now, $-2\cdot x=-14.08$) is $270^\circ$.
It is confusing to think that such connecting line is a vertical line. 
Request some tool that enables one to visualize such un-intuitive angle. If there is a site, applet, tool, or logic to make one see the same intuitively; then please tell.

Comment: This question is far fro self-contained enough to be understandable to me. The tangent slopes of $y=x^3$ vary between $0°$ and (in the limit) $90°$. If you go "backwards", 90° is of cours turned into 270°. However, these extremes are only reached in the limit. With finite places, you can only get arbitraily close to that.

Comment: I hope my edit makes it clearer, that there is an infinite sequence of tangents with their $x$ coordinates having a geometric ratio of $-2$. The angle of $90^0$ (for tangents made from 3rd quad to first), or $270^0$ (for vice-versa) is approached very quickly for a small starting $x$ value, say $x=+0.11$; it takes 6 steps in the sequence to get slope of a vertical line (i.e. $90^0$, or $270^0$).

Comment: I still don't see where you get a vertical tangent (as opposed to an *almost* vertical tangent)

Comment: For example, (taken fro the last line of your code output), $\arctan$ of $-6.19244948763\cdot 10^{13}$ is not $-90^\circ$, but merely $-89.999999999999074747729^\circ$ (approximately, also depends on whet un-rounded value is behind $-6.19244948763\cdot 10^{13}$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But, to get such a slope (near vertical line) is un-intuitive to me. Say, the two points $x = 7.04, -14.08$ are on separate halves of $x$-axis; then how is any amount of $y$ coordinate difference going to generate a near vertical line, is not logical to me.

Comment: it suffices to have $f(7.04)-f(-14.08)\ge 21.12\cdot 6.19244948763\cdot 10^{13}$ I am unsure however, how this relates to the functon $f(x)=x^3$ that you seem to investigate.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen These are values of successive tangents' $x$-coordinates, with $x$-coordinates values lying in G.P. with common ratio of $-2$. So, for $n=6$, the $x$ coordinate is having value $7.04$, while for $n=7, x$ coordinate is $-14.08$. Next comes value of cubic curve $y= f(x)$ at those $x$-coordinates. As an aside, an interesting fact is that the $x$-coordinates of successive tangents are dependent only on the previous $x$ values.-----The post in which these successive tangents are discussed is specified as link, in the post linked above (so, the current post is 3rd in that chain).