# Is a formal proof possible to show that a system with multiple identities is not a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a group, need a both-sided identity. I  know just which four properties (*1. closure, 2. associativity of operator on the group elements, 3. unique both-sided identity, 4. unique inverse of each element to be among the elements of the group*) are needed for a group.

I tried to reason with an example, with algebraic systems that don't have a unique both-sided identity, as below:

Multiple one-side identities: In the case of system $(\mathbb{Q}, o)$ with operation $o$ defined as $xoy = x^2y$. It has two left identities: $-1, 1$.
The reason here seems simple - it is not possible to have a right-side identity.

But, is there any formal proof possible for the above fact, using a simple level of a novice in group theory - knowing nothing more than the four conditions of group.

---

*Update* I want to formally state my query in face of response by @Arthur:

I have a situation with multiple identity on one side - say $x_1, x_2$ (am taking none as right-identity, as reasoned above, that there can be no right identity in this case, i.e. with multiple left identities). So, if take hypothetically $y$ as a right-identity; then how to show that $x_1x_2y$ is not a possibility, and only $x_1x_2$ is possible; with my knowledge level as constraint.

---

*Update 2* In face of not getting a *clear* response from community, I feel the implied message is that : the property of groups is that a left identity is also  a right identity; so if right identity is shown above to not exist with multiple left identities; then there is no group. 
But, I requested something formal to state the same.

Comment: If $e$ is a left identity and $f$ is a right identity then $e\cdot f$ is both equal to $e$ and $f$ and therefore $e=f$. I think this is the standard proof.

Comment: @N.Ciccoli Why are you putting an answer in the comment section?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Have made my question more clear as comment to the Arthur's answer.

Comment: @MorganRodgers You gave a pretty decent hint. Those should still be in answer posts. Also, they still give help to the asker, who you yourself seem to think doesn't deserve it.

Comment: As per my level, I feel this question is good and needed one for a beginner (like me) to progress with limited knowledge at hand, and is not seen by me anywhere so far, so request reason for closing it.

Comment: Your update 2 is nonsense. There are clear answers in the comments.

Comment: Suggestion. You stand back from this and prove that any system with a binary associative operation with (a) at least one left-identity $e$ (b) for each element there is at least one left-inverse is a Group, with $e$ being a right inverse.

Comment: Your operation $x \circ y = x^2y$ is not associative. Therefore it cannot be a group operation. Is that what you are after, or is that operation just a bad example?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I hope that approach is : proving that a system with at least one left-identity $e$, & at least one left-inverse for each element is a Group. But, could not understand the last line - i.e. : 'with $e$ being a right inverse'. I can at max. see that $e$ must be a right identity, but to be a right-inverse is something confusing to me.

Comment: @ccorn It is a bad example, but is not - as emphasis was on showing a case with two left identities not having a right one. May be, it is the way (that associativity is never followed in this case) to key for a formal proof; but don't know how to pursue.

Comment: If there is a left inverse $x^{-1}$ to $x$ and several left identities $e_1,e_2$, then which identity is given by $x^{-1}x$? The concept of "left inverse" would not be well defined in this case.

Comment: @ccorn This is a valid and possibly shorter method than proving that associativity does not hold in such case. The basic premise is well-definedness, or being deterministic. This determinism is then to connect an element to its inverse, i.e. the same element is picked up as 'left inverse' each time when identity (any) is applied. So, because of assuming unique left-inverse, it is invalid to be group. --- But, above argument (if correct) means that need assumption of left inverse. I mean that might be can prove by another way- that uses a still smaller assumption. Sorry, put no thought on it

Comment: I am very sorry I meant "right identity".

Comment: The updates and comments mean I can no longer understand the question. Can you please clarify: are you assuming $G$ is a group satisfying your (1),(2),(3),(4) and asking whether it can also have another element $e'$ which is a left-identity? If not please specify exactly what you are assuming about $G$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, I know of the $4$ group properties, and want to formally prove that there cannot be more than one left-identities in a group.

Comment: Now *I* am confused. Aren't you trying to relax some group properties (re: identity, inverse) and show that those still follow from the other ones?

Comment: Perhaps try to be more formal: Let $G$ be a set and $\circ\colon\ G\times G\mapsto G$ an associative operation, and assume that there exist left identities $e_1,e_2\in G$ with respect to $\circ$, (more properties...). Does $e_1=e_2$ follow?

Comment: Thanks jiten. In that case @N.Ciccoli's comment three hours ago answers the question completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question is still rather unclear.

- As I wrote before it is easily seen that a left and a right identity should coincide.
- As ancientmathematician commented if you have more than one left identity you should clarify what you mean by unique inverse. In fact if $e_1g=g=e_2g$ for any $g\in G$ then multiplying on the right by $g^{-1}$ should give you an answer once you clarified what you mean by inverse.
- The only possible way to obtain multiple inverses is to require that not all elements can be multiplied one with the other. This leads to the (interesting) notion of groupoid.

(hope this satisfies Arthur's standards on what an answer should be)

Answer (score 0):

If we have two two-sided identity elements $x,y$ (or even just if there is a left identity $x$ and a right identity $y$), then
$$
x=xy=y
$$
so they are actually the same element. This is the reason you can't have two distinct identity elements.

Comment: I have a situation with multiple identity on one side - say with your example $x_1, x_2$ (am taking none as right-identity, as reasoned in OP, that there can be no right identity in this case, i.e. with multiple left identities). So, if take hypothetically $y$ as a right-identity; then how to show that $x_1x_2y$ is not a possibility, and only $x_1x_2$ is possible.

Comment: I hope my last update to  OP makes my question even more clear.