# Is inverse possible for getting identity element ($e$) for binary exponentiation operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

I am assuming two domains below: integers ($\mathbb{Z}$), & rationals($\mathbb{Q}$); with common identity element $1$.

The binary exponentiation operator yields for the simplest case of two integers, $a,b$: $c = a^b= a*a*\cdots a$ (b times).

An identity element means that on multiplying $a^b$ by something like $c$ as inverse yields $1$ element of the set.

So, $c = \frac1{a^b}\implies a^b = \frac1c$
$\implies$
Taking natural log on both sides $b = \frac1{ln(a)}\cdot ln(\frac1{c})$, so it is clear that integers are not capable to have inverse  w.r.t. the exponentiation operator; only rationals can.

However, integers are closed w.r.t. the exponentiation operator.

Also, need help to convert the above argument for proving that inverse for the domain of rationals would exist, for the exponentiation operator.

Comment: There isn't one.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown But why not for the domain of rationals. Please show.

Comment: If you could edit your question, then it might be helpful; right now, I [personally] do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I want proof for existence of inverse under the exponentiation operation, in the domain of rationals. I have proved that inverse is not possible for integers, for the given operation.

Comment: are you dealing with exponentiation or multiplication? are you learning group theory or are you learning other topic?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Sorry for delayed response due to exigency. I am learning group theory. However, the topic was found in the book : The Number systems & Operations of arithmetic, by Orval Klose, on pg. #140, as shown at : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WuVw.png . The book discusses all basic number systems including complex, rationals, reals.

Comment: Binary operators can have right-identities (*elements $r$ such that $x*r=x$ for all $x$*) and left-identities (*elements $\ell$ such that $\ell * x = x$ for all $x$*).  If both happen to exist then $r = \ell * r = \ell$ and they are the same element and we just call it an "identity" without reference to right or left.  You should be able to convince yourself that $1$ is a right-identity for exponentiation since $x^1=x$ for all $x$.  You should further be able to convince yourself that $1$ is not the left-identity implying no left-identity exists (*since if it did it would have to be 1*).

Comment: @JMoravitz Please vet my response: This leads to only right identity, so can it be used for finding inverse under exponentiation operator with identity $e=1$, over rationals? (I am asking this as a novice). If yes, then that entails having another rational element, let $c$ s.t. $a^c = e\implies c\cdot ln(a) = 0$, as the unit element (here $1$). So, finding inverse is impossible; or equivalently $a^e = e^a = a$, which is also not possible, unless $a=e$.

Comment: Inverses aren't defined without corresponding identity.  We don't have an identity, only a right identity which is not the same thing.  Since we don't have an identity we don't have inverses either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are dealing with the exponentiation operation.

I claim that there is no identity element, $e$ for this operation for the set $X$, where $X$ can be either $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}$, or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose there is such element then we must have $\forall a \in X, e^a =a^e=a$. If such element exists, we know that it is unique. From, $a^e=a$, we know that $e=1$. However, this means that $1^a=a$, we reach a contradiction if $a=2$. Hence, the identity doesn't exists and there is no inverse to talk about.

Comment: Sorry, unable to understand. I mean that why we need $e^a =a$, but it is fine & obvious that $a^e = a$.

Comment: To be the identity element of operation $*$ for set $X$, we need $\forall a \in X, a*e=e*a=a$ isn't it? in this case $a*e=a^e$ and $e*a=e^a$.

Comment: So, it is in the context of group theory that this restriction is placed. But, suppose if it were a general problem over rationals ($\mathbb{Q}$), then would have identity $=1$, as there would be inverse possible for rationals ($\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: hmm... it depends on what do you mean by "general". you might want to define things clearly if you are not using a [conventional definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element)

Comment: I fear no modification is possible that allows both the 'general' view, as well as the view imposed by group structure; so explain here. By 'general' problem, I mean that over rationals need find an inverse element (let, $g$) for every value $d = e^f, e,f, g\in \mathbb{Q}, e\ne 0$, s.t. $dg =1$.

Comment: Are you asking if for every $f, g \in \mathbb{Q}$, does there exists an element $g \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $e^fg=1$? Answer is no.

Comment: Yes, I am asking that, but cannot understand why, may be need a counter-example, as cannot construct a proof for the same.

Comment: counterexample, $e=2, f=\frac12$

Comment: So, if include irrationals in the domain(set of values possible for $e,f$); then the value $c=e^f$ is closed w.r.t. exponentiation (i.e., the value $c$ is in the same set ); hence get an inverse all the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79974/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten).

Comment: Please help with formulating algorithm, for evaluating cycles to form final set of mappings, as addendum to my OP at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2850286/424260. The confusion is in the 3rd case, as shown by my comments to the lone answer.

Comment: Please help with my post at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2892297/424260, particularly the update. Also, can the answers/comments to the original post be construed to prove by extension that all polynomial functions (of odd/even degree) are surjective.