# Non-unique representation of permutations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

Permutations are stated to be having non-unique representation as given below, in the text of Stahl, titled: Introductory Modern Algebra, on pg. #164; as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2cnV.png).

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$

Am unable to understand it, and want to understand some part of it to get the reasoning behind it:
1. Say, can understand the starting part, i.e. for  $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$, have first (taking mappings occurring from right cycle to left)  $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$, then  $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$; i.e. first $2 \longrightarrow 3$, then $1 \longrightarrow 2$.
2. But, the next one is not comprehensible to me, as $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$; which should mean that $1 \longrightarrow 2, (2\longrightarrow 1)$, then $1 \longrightarrow 3, (3\longrightarrow 1)$. This means $1$ maps to both $2,3$ in that ordering.
3. Similarly, the 3rd one is confusing, as it states $1 \longrightarrow 3, (3\longrightarrow 1)$, then $2 \longrightarrow 3, (3\longrightarrow 2)$.
This means $3$ is mapped to by both $1, 2$ in that ordering.
I hope that if the confusion in the 2nd, 3rd points above are removed; then would help me in understanding the rest too.

---

In view of the answer by @G. Smith, have made an addendum. I want to make an algorithmic sort of evaluation for the same, & request modification of my method below: 
Assumptions:- There is going to form relationships between elements in a cycle, with origin_end, & recipient_end, shown as left & right member of the arrow. so,
 $a\longrightarrow  b$ has $a$ as the origin_end, $b$ as the recipient_end.

1- Proceed from right to left, taking one cycle at a time  <del>with right cycle given priority to decide
 $\,\,\,\,$ relationship over left one for common origin_end, or recipient_end between $\ge$ two cycles</del>.
2- $\,\,\,\,$ List the cycle members with two sets of relationships, 
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$ (a) explicitly given, (b) implicitly given. 
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$ E.g. $(a\,\, b)$ with explicit relation as $a \longrightarrow b$, & implicit relation as $b \longrightarrow a$. 
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$ The implicit relation can be modified by earlier left, or further right cycles.
3- $\,\,\,\,$ The

---

Update: In view of the answer by @Siong, have got a graph approach with vertices representing nodes, and edges representing the transpositions given. The edges are bi-directional, and the graph is limited by the transpositions (edges) given between the vertices.

The graph for the example 1.1 (2nd) link referred in comments [below](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/sign.pdf), is shown by a graph [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW1zS.png). The transpositions are numbered from left-to-right, and the common ones are having the same edge; e.g. edge #1,4,10 stand for edge between nodes: 1, 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{pmatrix} x_0 & x_1 & \ldots & x_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$ means $x_i \to x_{i+1 \pmod n} $ and if any term doesn't appear, identity is being applied to the element.

Hence $\begin{pmatrix} x_0 & x_1 \end{pmatrix}$ means $x_0 \to x_1$ and $x_1 \to x_0$.

Given an element $x$,$$\begin{pmatrix} x_0 & x_1\end{pmatrix}x=\begin{cases} x_1 & , x=x_0 \\ x_0 &, x=x_1 \\
x &, \text{Otherwise.}&\end{cases}$$

Now let's evaluate $\begin{pmatrix}2  & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}$.

$$\begin{pmatrix}2  & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}[1]=\begin{pmatrix}2  & 3 \end{pmatrix}[3]=2$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}2  & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}[2]=\begin{pmatrix}2  & 3 \end{pmatrix}[2]=3$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}2  & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}[3]=\begin{pmatrix}2  & 3 \end{pmatrix}[1]=1$$

We can see that it is equivalent to $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks, applied your approach of applying the mapping(s) provided to each element, for the 2nd case. I mean that:  $$\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1  & 2 \end{pmatrix}[1]=\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}[2]=2,$$ $$\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1  & 2 \end{pmatrix}[2]=\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}[1]=3$$ $$\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1  & 2 \end{pmatrix}[3]=\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}[3]=1$$. Also, your approach makes the algorithm as simple as anything.

Comment: I request your kind response for the below statement: If the 2nd case instead had a reverse ordering of the cycles, i.e. $(1\,\, 2)(1\,\,3)$, then desired mapping is not possible for element $2$, as it maps to $1$. So, is there a (reverse) way to tell which set of ordering(s) would lead to the desired mapping. I am quite confused on this issue, & suspect some usage of transitive closure based on graph algorithms for that.

Comment: If $c$ is a cycle and $a,b$ are transposition and $c=ab$. Note that we have $a=a^{-1}$ and $b=b^{-1}$. We have $c^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$. In general if you reverse the order of composition of transpostion, what you obtain is the inverse of the cycle.

Comment: I agree that as $(1\,\,2)(1\,\,3)$ should produce a reverse mapping, i.e. same as $(1\,\,3\,\,2)$; & it can be proved as follows: $$\begin{pmatrix}1  & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}[1]=\begin{pmatrix}1  & 2 \end{pmatrix}[3]=3$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}1  & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}[2]=\begin{pmatrix}1  & 2 \end{pmatrix}[2]=1$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}1  & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}[3]=\begin{pmatrix}1  & 2\end{pmatrix}[1]=2$$.

Comment: I hope have asked a wrong question earlier, as for a given ordering of cycles, the possible set of mappings can only be found by working for each element, by your way. I mean that there can be no reverse way to find out which all ordering(s) of cycles would lead to a given desired mapping; i.e. to get $1\longrightarrow 2, 2\longrightarrow 3, 3\longrightarrow 1$, it is not possible to get the possible orderings of cycles, i.e. the r.h.s. of the question, or $(1\,\,2)(1\,\,3)$ & others. Only the r.h.s. orderings have to be worked out manually to get the all possible orderings.

Comment: hmm.... no idea what is being asked....

Comment: Missed one line from last comment:  Hoped some graph algorithm using transitive closure for it. ---- If you wish, can chat so that can explain my point. Please tell me to join, if possible.

Comment: Are you asking given that given a cycle $C$ and we decompose it to transposition $C=T_1T_2 \ldots T_k$, what are all the possible permutation of $T_i$ such that their product still give you $C$?

Comment: Yes, but took time to understand the same (i.e., your last comment). I googled with 'transpositions of a cycle permutation', & read first at : http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/sign.pdf. Am not finished reading it, as some difficult product of transpositions are there, i.e. the second one in Ex. 1.1.

Comment: i have no idea how to find all decomposition of a cycle.

Comment: Am stuck at second example given in Ex. 1.1. of link. Need get from $\sigma = (12)(34)(23)(12)(23)(34)(45)(34)(23)(12)$. So, working from right end, get (used \longrightarrow for new transposition; while \rightarrow for derived mapping): $(a) 1\longrightarrow 2, 2\longrightarrow 3 \implies 1\rightarrow 3; (b) 1\rightarrow 3, 3\longrightarrow 4\implies 1\rightarrow 4; (c) 1\rightarrow 4, 4\longrightarrow 5\implies 1\rightarrow 5; (d) 3\longrightarrow 4;...$. From $(d)$ on-wards, am unable to solve to get the final cycle $C$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80180/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten).

Comment: My graph (shown in chat, & link given in *Update*) is for 2nd ex. of Q. 1.1 as in my last 2 comments. In 2nd set of transpositions 'fictitious' edges are used, when compared to first example; as in graph 'all' nodes are reachable by bi-directional edges.The 1st example is illustr. by graph at https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRTtf.png. Want to develop on the 'new' graph, but don't know how to introduce 'fictitious edges' as needed for the 2nd example. Am working on link http://www1.spms.ntu.edu.sg/~frederique/lecture7ws.pdf; & expect to find a graphical approach based on the matrix approach there.

Comment: I request your help on a linked post (to this topic of graphical rep. of alternate transpositions) at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2898266/424260.

Comment: Please help me with my last two comments.

Comment: I am still puzzled about what you are trying to do...

Comment: I am confused what is the reason why graphical approach is not the way to look at a permutation's transpositions. Why one set of transpositions' graph does not fit the other. The core reason should be how the actual graphical approach should be. May be it is a function-based approach, & hence matrix approach works; but graphical has no sense here.

Comment: Any help would be great to me.

Comment: Please give some inputs. My linked post also has attracted no response of any kind so far.

Comment: I don't have a solution now.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation of the first one isn't clear, so I think that's why you don't understand the second one.

Let's look at the first one, $(12)(23)$. What happens to $1$, when first applying $(23)$ and then $(12)$? Well, $(23)$ doesn't change $1$ and then $(12)$ maps $1$ to $2$. So $1\to2$. What happens to $2$? $(23)$ maps it to $3$ and then $(12)$ doesn't change $3$. So $2\to3$. What happens to $3$? $(23)$ maps it to $2$, and then $(12)$ maps $2$ to $1$. So $3\to1$. Putting this together, we have $1\to2$, $2\to3$, $3\to1$, which is what $(123)$ means.

Now let's look at the second one, $(13)(12)$. What happens to $1$? $(12)$ maps it to $2$, and then $(13)$ leaves $2$ alone, so $1\to2$. What happens to $2$? $(12)$ maps it to $1$, and then $(13)$ maps $1$ to $3$, so $2\to3$. What happens to $3$? $(12)$ leaves it $3$, and then $(13)$ maps $3$ to $1$, so $3\to1$. So again we have $1\to2$, $2\to3$, $3\to1$ or $(123)$.

You should be able to follow the same logic for the others.

Comment: Thanks for solving the confusion for the 2nd case. Please give an explanation for the 3rd case too, as am unable to solve on my own. Here $1 \longrightarrow 3$ is followed by $2 \longrightarrow 3$, i.e. from right to left. If follow your logic, then : - (i) the first (right one) leaves $2$, (ii) while the second (left one) leaves $1$, & (iii) second (left one) has implied relationship: $3 \longrightarrow 2$. This leads to :  $1\longrightarrow 3\longrightarrow 2$, which is not the same as $(1 \,\, 2\,\, 3)$.

Comment: Or should I take that -- take implied mapping from left to get $3 \longrightarrow 1$, to merge with explicit mapping given by right to get: $2 \longrightarrow 3$ to get implied mapping $1 \longrightarrow 2$. But, this is not obvious as there are only two explicit orderings given in left & right cycles, i.e. $1 \longrightarrow 3, 2 \longrightarrow 3$. Bigger issue: cannot implement algorithmic way, as going by 3rd case need equal priorities of both left cycle, and right cycle (for 2 cycle case), for getting which cycle dominates for getting explicit (shown) mapping.

Comment: After Siong Thye Goh's clearer answer, you probably understand how to do it. Yes? If so, you should remove the addendum to your question. By the way, just think of $(12)$ as standing for the mapping $1\to2$,$2\to1$, $3\to3$. Don't think about some of them being "explicit" and some "implicit". Do the mappings right to left, feeding the result of the previous mapping to the next one.

Comment: I want to learn from the mistakes made in framing addendum, so am not deleting it. When I feel confident enough to not needing to learn; would delete it. Else, tell me how to hide it, as \hide{text}, \color{white}{text} are useless as produce no effect at all, & are repeated verbatim in output.