# Why function $x\to x^3 -x$ over reals is surjective?

Tags: functions

To prove, need show that $x^3 -x = x(x-1)(x+1)$ has entire real number line mapped. 
This is not clear to me, as reals would not be dependent (logically) on multiplication of $3$ terms, separated by $1,2$, i.e. between $(x, x-1)$ or $(x, x+1)$; or $(x-1, x+1)$.

---

*Update :* The above question is from the R.P. Burn book titled: Groups: A Path to Geometry. I intend to extend this to ask if it is possible to prove that the above function is injective over positive reals, for all values except $(1,0)$, i.e. $f(x) = x^3 -x$ is injective for $\mathbb{R+}$ minus either of the the two values of $0,1$; as at these two values function has a common value. 
The purpose behind this self-extension is to gain further insight.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Please elaborate, as IVT is for finding roots.

Comment: Can you show that this hits a particular value - like can you show this hits $27$ somewhere?

Comment: It goes to $-\infty$ as $x\to -\infty$, it goes to $+\infty$ as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: For using IVT, note that $f(x)=c$ is equivalent to $f(x)-c=0$. So if you know how to find roots, you can easily use that to find any other value.

Comment: As @lulu suggested and you can show that this is nowhere discontinuous so it maps all the real numbers.

Comment: @MiloBrandt $27 = x(x-1)(x+1) =27\implies $ need use numerical approximation to find exact $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Let $f$ be any odd degree polynomial with positive leading coefficient. (Which is the case here for your quesiton)

It is surjective as $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)= -\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, and use the property that a polynomial is continuous, by intermediate value theorem, it obtains every single real number.

To be more detailed, let $y \in \mathbb{R}$, to show that the function is surjective, we have to find an element $c$ in the domain, in this case $\mathbb{R}$, such that $f(c)=y$.

Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty, \exists M_1 > 0, \forall x > M_1, f(x) > |y|$. In particular $f(2M_1) > |y|$.

Since $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty, \exists M_2 > 0, \forall x < - M_2, f(x) < - |y|$. In particular $f(-2M_2) < -|y|$.

Hence $$f(-2M_2) < -|y| \le y \le |y| < f(2M_1)$$

Hence there is a value $c \in (-2M_2, 2M_1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(c)=y$ by intermediate value theorem.

The argument works for any continuous function that satisfies $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$ and it is not restrictive to polynomial.

- Similar argument applies when the leading coefficient is negative and of course in general it works for any continuous function that satisfies $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and it is not restrictive to polynomial.

Remark:

- However, this is not the case for even degree polynomial. In fact, there is no surjective even degree polynomial. Suppose the leading coefficient is positive, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = \infty$, and we can find $M$ such that $|x| > M$ then $f(x) > 1$. The range is $f((-\infty, -M)) \cup f([-M, M]) \cup f((M, \infty))  \subseteq (1, \infty) \cup f([-M,M])$. Hence $f$ has a minimum and any value lower than the minimum value is not attainable. The argument applies to any continuous function that satisfies $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = \infty$. Similar result holds for continuous function that satisfies $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$.

Regarding your update, it is unclear to me what do you mean by $(1,0)$. To discuss about a function, we should state the domain, codomain and the rule. Suppose your function is

$$g: [1, \infty) \mapsto [0, \infty), g(x) = x^3-x,$$

then $g$ is injective because $g$ is an increasing function.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. Sorry, for specifying the removal of two values $0,1$ in wrong format. Also, your specification would imply domain as $\mathbb{R+}$ & co-domain as $\mathbb{R+}$ plus $0$. But, I am not sure about the increasing function $g=x^3-x$ taking all possible values of the co-domain. Request more inputs on this.

Comment: You mean your domain is $(0,1) \cup (1, \infty)$? In that case, it is not injective.  we can see that the horizontal line cut the curve twice in this [desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ise8igj1nl), My domain for $g$ is $[1, \infty)$. Injective means no two values in the domain share the same function value. hence if a function is increasing, $x < y \iff f(x) < f(y)$.

Comment: If I take your assumption of domain, but even then it is not possible for me to see how the function is injective. I hope that need prove the function as increasing one by taking the first derivative as : $3x^2 - 1$; then second as $6x$. But, if am not wrong, the positive second derivative is for decreasing functions.

Comment: to know whether a function is increasing or decreasing, just look at the firts derivative. The second derivative convey convexity information.

Comment: Kindly see my post at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2895702/424260, for finding distance between two points on oblique axes.

Comment: Please help me with my earlier comment.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for $$f(x)=x^3-x$$ we have the following limits.

$$\lim _{x\to -\infty }f(x)= -\infty$$

and 
$$\lim _{x\to \infty }f(x)= \infty$$

To show that $f$ is surjective, let $y\in \mathbb {R} $ be an arbitrary real number.

From the first limit, we have some real number $a$ such that $f(a)<y$ and from the second limit we find a real number $b$ such that $f(b)>y$

Since $f$ is a continuous function on the interval $[a,b]$  and $f(a)<y<f(b)$ the intermediate value theorem provides a real number $c$ such that $f(c)=y$

Thus $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x) = x^3-x$ you specified satisfies the following: As $x$ goes to $\infty$ the value $f(x)$ goes to $\infty$ as well. Therefore, as $f$ is a continuous real-valued function and $f(1)=0$, it follows that for every $y \in [0,\infty) \cap \mathbb{R}$, there is an $x$ such that $f(x)=y$ [make sure you see this, you need both continuity and real-valued]

and as $x$ goes to $-\infty$ the value of $f(x)$ goes to $-\infty$ as well. Thus, using the same reasoning as in the above paragraph, for every $y \in (\infty,0] \cap \mathbb{R}$, there is an $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.

So for each $y \in ([0,\infty) \cap \mathbb{R}) \cup ((\infty,0] \cap \mathbb{R})$, there is an $x$ s.t. $f(x)=y$. As $([0,\infty) \cap \mathbb{R}) \cup ((\infty,0] \cap \mathbb{R})$ is in fact $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$, there is an $x$ s.t. $f(x)=y$. And so by definition of "surjective" the desired result follows.

Comment: Please elaborate it more, or provide link to some other post/site.

Comment: Did you mean to write $y \in (-\infty, 0] \cap \mathbb{R}$?  Check the second and third paragraphs.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes I did. Good catch!

Comment: In that case, you should edit your second and third paragraphs accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach: assume that $x^3-x$ does not take the value $v\in\mathbb{R}$. Then the polynomial $x^3-x-v$ has no real root, which is a contradiction since every element of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ with an odd degree has at least one real root (complex roots come into conjugated pairs).

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

$f: x\mapsto x^3-x $ is continuous at $\Bbb R$.

$$\lim_{-\infty}f=-\infty$$

$$\lim_{+\infty}f=+\infty$$

thus

$$f(\Bbb R)=\Bbb R$$